# How to change the cookie to session in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage, session-cookies

[image]

I am new to cookies. I have the existing code using cookies. I want to change the cookie to the session storage now. How to do it

```
if (My.Cookie.getCookie('cookie1') !== "true") {

}

if (!data) {
  // some code
} else {
   My.Cookie.setCookie('cookie1', "true");
}
```

Comment: I think you want to `localStorage.nameCookieHere = JSON.stringify(ObjectOfYourCookies);`. You have to have created the cookie to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`sessionStorage.SessionName = "SessionData"`

`sessionStorage.getItem("SessionName")`

`sessionStorage.setItem("SessionName","SessionData");`